# glReadPixels How to get pixel value

Tags: python, opengl, pyopengl

I use this function to return such a value. I hope to get the RGB value of each pixel, which is 0 to 255, not 0 to 1. What should I do

```
data = glReadPixels(0,0, w, h, GL_RGB,GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE)
print(data)
```

output

```
\xd1\x9e\xad\xd1\x9e\xad\xd1\x9e\xad\xd1\x9e\xad\xd1\x9e\xad\xd1\x9e\xad\xd1\x9e\xad\xd1\x9e\xad\xd1\x9e\xad\xd1\x9e\xad\xd1\x9e\xad\xd1\x9e\xad\xd1\x9e\xad\xd1\x9e\xad\xd1\x9e\xad\xd1\x9e\xad\xd1\x9e\xad\xd1\x9e\xad\xd1\x9e\xad\xd1\x9e\xad\xd1\x9e\xad\xd1\x9e\xad\xd1\x9e\xad\xd1\x9e\xad
```

[image]

Comment: You should probably start with specifying language/environment that you use because [`glReadPixels`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glReadPixels.xhtml) does not return anything per specification.

Comment: Also what you shown as output looks like byte array in some string representation. Isn't that what you want?

Comment: Is this not the pixel data?

Comment: Is the problem solved?

Answer (score 0):

Use [`numpy.frombuffer`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.frombuffer.html) to convert the string to a byte array:

```py
import numpy
```

```py
data = glReadPixels(0, 0, w, h, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE)
byte_array = numpy.frombuffer(data, dtype='uint8')
print(list(byte_array))
```

Or use [`ctypes.from_buffer_copy`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ctypes.html#ctypes._CData.from_buffer_copy)

```py
import ctypes
```

```py
data = glReadPixels(0,0, w, h, GL_RGB,GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE)
byte_array = (ctypes.c_ubyte * (w * h * 3)).from_buffer_copy(data)
print(list(byte_array))
```